# warning: Unsupported Configuration: Image and Title are set (These attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4

Unsupported Configuration Image and Title are set These attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored..... while running my project in xcode i am getting this warning because of this warning my application compiling too slow.........so plz tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: Please be more explanatory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be pretty obvious. You set, most likely a bar button item, to a system one (Cancel, Done....) but also provided a custom title. You can't do both, so it's ignoring your custom title...refered by http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/92531-ib-warnings.html

Comment: i am expecting better answer

Comment: For that the question should be asked betterly :)

Comment: I found a trash bar item with a title set to "Item". Unfortunately, Xcode allowed me to set the title (or some version of Xcode did this for me?) for a system item and later would not take me to the offending warning when I selected it. After a fair amount of searching I found it manually.